# Vertically Aligning H2 Span to centre of DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align a h2 span that says 'My Caption' along the middle of the DIV vertically.

I tried to use `vertical - align` but that property didn't change the positioning of the photo.

I am using bootstrap and the problem is that as the page window becomes smaller, the text dissapears due to the relative positioning that only works the most at the moment.

```css
.imageInside { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h2 {
   line-height:100px; 
   vertical-align:middle; 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 0; 
   left: 10; 
   width: 100%; 
}

h2 {
 z-index:1;
}

h2 span { 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 0.8em 'montserratsemi_bold', Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
  <title>Tutorial</title>
  <!-- Tab Title -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- 960 Grid -->
  
  <style>
  .imageInside { 
     position: relative; 
     width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
  }

  h2 {
     line-height:100px; 
     vertical-align:middle; 
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 10; 
     width: 100%; 
  }

  h2 {
   z-index:1;
  }

  h2 span { 
     color: white; 
     font: bold 0.8em 'montserratsemi_bold', Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
     letter-spacing: -1px;  
     background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
     padding: 10px; 
  } 
  </style>
  
 </head>
 <body>
  
  <div class="container">
   
   <div class = "row">

    <div class="imageHolder col-md-12 middle" style="margin-top:10px;"> 

     <div class = "imageInside hvr-underline-from-center" >
      <img id = "imageHomeJPG" src="http://bit.ly/1lhHK4t" style="width:100%" />
      <h2><span>My Caption.</span></h2>
     </div>

       </div> 
   </div> 
   
   </div>
   
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Please view the snippet in full screen to see the true result.

[image: Result seen in smaller window]

I used the following tutorial. https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/

Thanks, David.

Comment: position: absolute; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);  for the h2 would do it (modern browsers - not ie8 for example) have a look here: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/ and - this has nothing to do with javaScript or jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeLjVX

the trick is from transform property!

```
 h2 {

      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: You have to use media queries to adjust that